# Is there an offline alternative to Hawaii for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, speech-recognition

Well I was looking for some way to translate speech to text offline on a **Windows Phone 7**, but all I could find is Hawaii which unfortunately needs connection to the internet. I need something that can work independently of the connection - offline.

Is there some kind of a library, service from Microsoft that could help me out with translating speech to text, in an offline mode?

Is there an offline alternative to the Hawaii for the Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Speech recognition is only available on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: A URL does not make a very good title... Hopefully the title I chose correctly summarizes your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of (for Windows Phone 7). Because there is no low-level access to speech APIs, your best bet would be either implementing your own speech recognition engine (max time/effort) - you have direct access to the microphone input, or using a web service (the most plausible option).